# Safely writing bytes to stream

Tags: c++, char, iostream

I need to write bytes to a file. The natural representation for a byte is `std::uint8_t`. The problem is that `istream.read()` and `ostream.write()` work with `char`s. I could convert between the two types, e.g.:

```
char c;
input.read(&c, 1);
uint8_t b = (uint8_t)c;
```

```
uint8_t b = …;
char c = (char)b;
output.write(&c, 1);
```

That could be a problem because `char` is often a signed type and AFAIK there is no guarantee what the bit pattern that is written will be the same as what the `int8_t` originally contained.

I need to make sure this works across compilers and OSes, so that if I write something on one computer, it will be read the same on any other one.

Is there any standards-compliant way to do this?

Comment: How about using `std::basic_istream<std::uint8_t>`, etc.?

Comment: try using `operator>>` and `operator<<` it avoid the issue you have with read and write only working with char's.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion from `unsigned char` to `char` and back is perfectly fine, and it's exactly what you should be doing. All three char types are layout compatible.

You only have to be careful with any non-char integral types and convert them to `uint8_t` first before converting to `char`, etc., and similarly in the other direction.

Comment: Does that mean that if `char` is signed, it is guaranteed to use two's complement?

Comment: @svick: it means neither of those, but neither are anything that needs worrying about.